# ESLint/Nodejs: Error linting due to default switch case

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

While trying to validate my .js file using ESLint I received a an unexpected lexical declaration (no-case declarations) error.

```
c:\>eslint C:\modules\myFile.js

503:17  error  Unexpected lexical declaration in case block        no-case-declarations
```

Following is my code that is causing the error

```
switch (type) {
case String(type.match(/.*test.*/i)):                        
        console.log('test')
        break;
default:
    console.log('error')
    return err;
}
```

There is no error shown in vs-code for this.
When i transform my code like:

```
switch (type) {
case String(type.match(/.*test.*/i)):                        
        console.log('test')
        break;
/*default:
    console.log('error')
    return err;*/
}
```

all errors disappear so I am thinking it must be coming off the default case block.

Following is my esLint.rc:

```
{
    "root": true,
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "script"
    },
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "browser": false
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "indent": ["error", 4, {
            "VariableDeclarator": 2,
            "SwitchCase": 1,
            "MemberExpression": 1,
            "ArrayExpression": "first"
        }],
        "no-mixed-requires": "off",
        "no-restricted-imports": "off",
        "no-undef":"off",
        "no-console":2,
        "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
        "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    }
}
```

What could be the issue here? As far as i read, the default ESLint rules have a **default-case rule** but **not** a **no-default-enforced** rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one cause it's not quite what you think. The default not having {...} is the problem. So changing default: to default: { ... } will fix this. If you want to turn it off, you'll have to remove an extension in eslint.

Specifically, this is being produced by the "extends" : "eslint:recommended"

[More information here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-case-declarations)